# При обновлении страницы, она поднимается вверх

Tags: html

При обновлении страницы, она поднимается вверх, а потом назад. Подскажите с чем это связанно, и как это исправить?
Я имею ввиду скролится в самый вверх, а потом в место где нажали кнопку - Обновить, допустим на средине. Спасибо.

Comment: А как у вас реализовано запоминание скролла?

Comment: Никак, просто если любую страницу обновить, на любом сайте, то она скролится быстро вверх а потом вниз, как можно это убрать?

Comment: Если вы никак не относитесь к разработке сайтов, где это происходит, то никак не уберете. Производится запоминание вашей позиции (но это не так часто практикуется), а после перезагрузки страницы в момент `document.ready` производится возврат к тому месту где вы были. Или же вы можете попробовать работать в другом браузере. Например в Mozilla FF такого запоминания не производится

Comment: Можно с Вами как-то связаться?

Comment: Да, здесь например